# Get type of class, that implement interface in that interface

Tags: c#

I need to know the type of class that implement an interface in this interface.

```
public interface SomeInterface
{
    public void Somemethod()
    {
        // Get 'ImplementationOfSomeInterface' here,
        // when Somemethod call by ImplementationOfSomeInterface.
        // Or get type of class that call this method.
    }
}

public class ImplementationOfSomeInterface : SomeInterface
{

}
```

My solution is:

```
public interface SomeInterface<T>
{
    public T Somemethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
        return (T)this;
    }
}

public class ImplementationOfSomeInterface : SomeInterface<ImplementationOfSomeInterface>
{

}
```

But, maybe better syntax exist.

If an interface like that is bad for an architecture of a program, just say about that, because I'm a noob at architecture. Then I'll try to use something else.

**EDIT 1**
I need to know type in signature of method.

**EDIT 2**
Try to explain.

```
public interface IContext<T>
{
    public T GetFormatContext()
    {
        return (T)this;
    }
}
public class App
{
    static public IContext<object> context;
}
public class Context : IContext<AnotherContext>
{
    public int field;
}
public class AnotherContext : IContext<AnotherContext>
{
    public string field;
}
public class Someclass
{
    public void UseContext()
    {
        // some code, that using certain context
    }
}
```

The `Someclass` *knows* which one of context is using at the moment. And, it needs just to use the fields, which contains in the context.

Comment: `this.GetType()`?

Comment: you don't need generics here, you can simply use `this.GetType()` within your interface-implementaion.

Comment: I thought about `this.GetType()`, but how I get the type in method signature?

Comment: @IGoogleBeforeAsking What do you mean? `public void Somemethod() => Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name);` would print `ImplementationOfSomeInterface`. No?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine No, `public T Something() => return (T)this;` needed.

Comment: Oh, you want the return type to be `ImplementationOfSomeInterface`? Why? If the class implements the interface, why don't you return the interface instead? Then you can cast it later.

Comment: seems like a really odd design. What if your class was this: `class MyClass : SomeInterface<AnotherClass>`? What should `SomeMethod` return in this case? We have too little information about what `SomeMethod` is supposed to do, in contrast to what you think the solution of your problem is. Having said this you should elaborate on what you actually want to **achieve** with this approach.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine In my case, in different classes different fields exist, and another classes must use those different fields. It's hard to explain. But, as I've said above, I'm noob at architecture.